# Trouble recognizing kanji from a manga

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

お、お前{まえ}ら

この変態{へんたい}を__えろ！！

I can't find a kanji that looks like the one in the image. For context, it's a guard/police officer yelling so I assume it's got something to do with arresting/capturing but even with that, I still cant find one that fits the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read it as [抑]{おさ}えろ: arrest. Hope that helps.